# Confusion in cin functionality with int dataype

Tags: c++

```
{

int n;
cin>>n;
cout<< n;

}
```

The output is `0` when `any alphabet or special character` is given as input.

In C its not the case when I used `scanf();` and `printf()`. It prints the corresponding ASCII value.

Please explain why is this happening?

Comment: Did you check the docs for the int overload of `>>`? And note, C != C++.

Comment: You may check `cin`'s state after inputting the value.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ cout<<cin.fail(); gives 1; and 0 only when its num. Why its failing ?

Comment: @MELWIN In C you also need to check the state of the extraction operation, see [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and read about the return value.

Comment: @MELWIN you are asking `cin` to read an `int` value, but you are then supplying it with alphabetical letters instead.  The conversion from characters to `int` fails accordingly.  `operator>>` for an `int` value can only read and parse digits, not letters.

Comment: maybe your C code used `scanf("%c"` instead of `%d`

Answer (score 1):

> Please explain why is this happening?

In the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) of the `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, int)` it's stated (emphasis mine):

> > If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), **value is left unmodified** and failbit is set.

For c++11 code it seems initialization is guaranteed:

> > If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set. If extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in value, `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` or `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()` is written and failbit flag is set.

Assumed you run a debug build of your code, `n` is probably initialized with `0` automatically, but technically accessing it is *undefined behavior*, since it wasn't initalized in that case you describe.

You have to check `cin`'s state after input to detect if a failure occured during the number extraction, or if you can safely use the now-initialized value:

```
 int n;
 std::cin >> n;
 if(std::cin) {
     std::cout << n << std::endl;
 }
 else {
     std::cin.clear(); // Clear the streams fail state
     std::string dummy;
     std::cin >> dummy; // Consume the non numeric input
     std::cout << "Wrong input, '" << dummy << "' is not a number."
 }
```

Comment: @Quentin THX, I've been bothering with that formulation there.

Comment: Do note the behavior is slightly different in C++11 and later: "*If extraction fails, **zero is written to value** and failbit is set.*"

Comment: @remy Adopted that.

Answer (score 0):

In both C and C++, when inputting an integer, the <s>driver</s> input function will read numeric characters until a character that is not a number is read.

For example, the sequence `"123GHI"` should return the value `123`.

Comment: Just asking, is `return` the correct term to be used here?

Comment: I believe so, as the input processes are functions and usually functions return a value.

Comment: "*should **output** the value 123*" would be more accurate. Output values are not always in function return values, and that is certainly the case in `operator>>` since the parsed value is output via a reference parameter not the return value.